# 2 SQL servers but different tempdb IO pattern on 1 spikes up and down 5MB/sec-0.2MB/sec

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2008

I have 2 MSSQL servers (lets call then SQL1 and SQL2) running a total of 1866 databases

- SQL1 has 993 databases (993203 registered users)
- SQL2 have 873 databases (931259 registered users)
  Each SQL server has a copy of a InternalMaster database (for some shared table data) and then multiple customers, 1 database per customer (Customer/client not registered user).

At the time of writing this we had just over 10,000 users online using our software.

SQL2 behaves as expected and Database I/O is generally 0.2MB/sec and goes up and down in a normal flow, IO's goes up on certain reports and queries and so on in a random fashion.
[image: SQL2 Database I/O and Batch Requests]

However SQL1 has a constant pattern almost like a life support machine.
[image: SQL1 Database I/O and Batch Requests]

I don't understand why both servers which have the same infrastructure, work so differently? The spike starts at around 2MB/sec and then increases to a max of around 6MB/sec. Both servers have identical IOPS provisions of data, log and transaction partitions and identical AWS specs. The Data file I/O shows that tempdb is the culprit of this spike.

[image: SQL1 Data File IO]

Any advice would be great as I just can't get my head around how 1 tempdb would act different to another when running the same software and setup on both servers.

Regards

Liam

Comment: The spike is now up to 8MB/sec and the same pattern...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liam,

Please see this website that explains how to configure TEMPDB. By looking at the image, you only have one file for the TEMPDB database.

http://www.brentozar.com/sql/tempdb-performance-and-configuration/

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Jorge, youre right, i only have 1 file. Ill have a look into this tomorrow :-) never crossed my mind about having multiple files for it. Ill feed back with results once tested. Thanks Liam

Comment: Hi Liam. It does help having multiple files since you have many databases.

Comment: Yeah im sirprised we havnt come across the issue before.. Ive never seen anyrhing in general setups about creating multiple before. But can see how this will help :-) We hit over 16,000 active users today so expexting to hit 20,000 over the next couple of weeks as more colleges start induction.

Comment: Please keep us posted if that helped.